# Flask official tutorial: what is 'e' in close_db(e=None)?

Tags: python, flask

In Flask's tutorial [[here]](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/database/), the definition for close_db included a default value for 'e=None'. But, this value isn't used in the function nor I can find reference anywhere.

```
def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()
```

Is there any specific reasons 'e=None' is explicitly stated?

Comment: Does anything happen if it’s removed?

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_appcontext: "When a teardown function was called because of an unhandled exception it will be passed an error object. "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll notice in the tutorial that in the `init_app` function, `close_db` is passed as an argument to `app.teardown_appcontext()`.

From the docstring for `teardown_appcontext`:

> When a teardown function was called because of an unhandled exception
> it will be passed an error object. If an `errorhandler` is
> registered, it will handle the exception and the teardown will not
> receive it.

So `e` refers to the error object, which is None by default. You can learn more about registering error handlers [at this link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/errorhandling/#registering).